# In gradle how do I disable the findbugs or checkstyle plugins for individual projects

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle, findbugs

We have a multi-project build in Java where two of the 8 projects are system tests and we don't want to run FindBugs or Checkstyle against the System test code (which is located in 'src/main/java').

I enable findbugs / checkstyle at the top-level build.gradle file but want to "disable" the plugin from running in these two projects?

Answer (score 6):

I love gradle it turned out to be quite simple

```
//Disable findbugs and checkstyle as per legacy ant build.xml
findbugs {
 sourceSets = []
}

checkstyle {
 sourceSets = []
}
```